# how to structure the data in order to use js-data firebase adapter

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jsdata

According to js-data documentation, this is how we define relationships between models (User and Comment for example)

```js
var User = store.defineResource({
  name: 'user',
  relations: {
    hasMany: {
      comment: {
        localField: 'comments',
        foreignKey: 'userId'
      }
    }
  }
}

var Comment = store.defineResource({
  name: 'comment',
  relations: {
    belongsTo: {
      user: {
        localField: 'user',
        localKey: 'userId'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But in Firebase we are storing data like this:

```
- root
  - users
    - $userId
        name
        email
        <no-user-id-here>
```

Will CRUD work in this case?

**Update:**

I tried but user.comments doesn't get updated

```js
// commentData
//  text: 'Hello'
//  userId: 'U12345'
Comment.create(commentData).then(function(comment) {
  return res.json(comment);
});
```